# My computer restore files by itself and I do not install any software

Tags: windows-10, file-management

System: Win10

Today morning, I tried to open Microsoft Edge and it report an error: 0xc0000005. I tried to reinstall it and I made a rar in order to avoid data loss. It can not be installed and I just restart the computer. Strangely, the RAR was disappeared and I did not care about it because I only want to fix up my browser. Then, I searched the internet for help and I found this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/application-error-0xc0000005/6224ae45-a251-4f21-b076-74524618d00a

I followed the introduction and ran:sfc /scannow the computer blue screen when it finished about 40%. Then, I restarted my computer and it seemed that it became normal again. I opened the Edge. However, when I closed it and opened it again, it reported the error again(I can only open it when the computer is just ready) . I do not know what's wrong.

I gave up and I was just typing and trying to finish my program. I changed a lot of code and I needed to eat my dinner so I closed my computer...

When I went back, I opened it again and my program was changed!! I recalled that the RAR had disappeared, too. And I knew what’s going on- it resets all things(by the way, each time I opened my computer and it asked me to input A1B2C3 because I tried too many times, this happened 3 weeks ago)

I made two txt on the computer and deleted all things in the recycle bin. When I restarted the computer, they were resetted. Even the windows defender configuration was resetted.

I did not install any resetting software and I examined the information about the boot area and it told me that the only system is Win10 so there is no resetting software. This morning, I tested it again and it still reset by itself.

I wonder what's wrong with my computer and I know litter about system so I described a lot bacause I do not know which information is useful.

I am really thankful for your attention because my English is bad and I may made some mistake(although I put it in google docs) If you need more information, please ask me, thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a faulty hard drive or a virus.

Comment: "I followed the introduction and ran:sfc /scannow the computer blue screen when it finished about 40%." - It should have finished at 100%, if it only reached 40%, then you have significant system corruption.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will examine them if nothing works I will reinstall the system.

Comment: Is this an SSD?

Comment: Yes, it is an SSD and 238GB in total, 147GB avliable.

Comment: Now the Edge is okay but chrome is bad. C\Program
FilesjGoogle\Chrome\Application\107.0.5304.121\chrome_elf.dll iseither not designed to run on windows or it contains an error.Tryinstalling the program again using the original installation media orcontact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.Error status oxco00012f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge is built into Windows and not separately uninstallable /installable.

**First:**  Check if you have hardware issues with your disk (over and above operating system issues) then software repairs will not work. Replace your drive.

**Second:** Run a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**Third:** If Repair Install / Keep Everything does not work, then back up and reinstall Windows 10.  Repair Install failure indicates damaged User Profile or very damaged Operating System and this is best solved by reinstalling Windows.